# Angular ngrepeat and paging with filters

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using angular's ng-repeat to present very large amounts of information. To handle this I've started using a filter.

I'm now trying to wrap it all in an angular directive that will handle paging by using a the ng-repeat and ng-filter, showing only X out of Y results. (results 100, showing 20-30).

I'm trying to present it in a similar way you'd encounter paging on an iPhone (with the number of pages represented as dots and clicking causing an animated scroll to another page).

As to my question, I'm stumped at what would be considered an 'angularish' way to solve my problem. The only real way I see to achieve this animation, is to render several divs, each with a certain width and perform a scroll between them. However, this doesn't really use the ng-filter's capabilities. I've also encountered the ng-animate class, but not sure how to achieve a paging effect with it.

Could anyone please direct me to a correct 'angularish' line of thought / solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be one

```
<div class="list-group" ng-init="quantity=100">
<div class="list-group-item pagingDiv" ng-cloak ng-repeat="(key,item) in MyDataArray| limitTo:quantity">
  .....
</div>
<div class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
   <button class="btn-block btn btn-primary" ng-click="quantity= quantity + 100">MORE.....</button>
</div>
```

For the CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .pagingDiv.ng-enter /*, .pagingDiv.ng-leave*/ {
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
        transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
    }

    .pagingDiv.ng-enter, .pagingDiv.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
        opacity: 0;
    }

        .pagingDiv.ng-leave, .pagingDiv.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
            opacity: 1;
        }

    /*.pagingDiv.ng-leave-stagger, .pagingDiv.ng-move-stagger,*/ .pagingDiv.ng-enter-stagger {
        -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
        transition-delay: 0.3s;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0;
        transition-duration: 0;
    }
</style>
```

> But for large data, i recommend to replace ng-click to call a function which retrieve the next page data and append it to MyDataArray